# How to prove the set G is a group with operation *

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let G be a set with the operation $*$. Then, suppose the associativity holds with respect operation $*$.
Assume that as for any $b\in G$,the map $\phi_{b}:G\to G$ defined by $\phi_{b}(g)=g*b$ is surjective and that there is an  $a\in G$ so that $\sigma_{a}:G\to G$ is surjective,where $\sigma_{a}(g)=a*g$. Prove that G is a group with the operation $*$.

I am stuck in this problem, firstly, we need to find the identity. However, I cannot figure out how to find the identity, if we can find the identity, then give any element a in G, we can use the surjectivity to know there is an inverse element $a^{-1}$ such that $a^{-1}*a$=e. Then, we can  prove the G is a group. However, I still have no idea how to find the identity of the set. Can someone give me some help?

Comment: sorry for typing,I just fixed some errors

Comment: Since $\sigma_a$ is surjective, there exists a $g_a$ so that $\sigma_a(g_a)=a$. Similarly, since for every $b$, $\phi_b$ is surjective, there's always a $h_b$ so that $\phi_b(h_b)=b$.

Comment: Now we have to prove that all these "putative unities" are in fact the same element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\phi_{a}$ is surjective, so there exists a $g_{1} \in G$ s.t. $g_{1}*a=a$. By the associativity, we have that $g_{1}*(a*h)=a*h,\forall h \in G$. But $\sigma_{a}$ is surjective, so we get
$$g_{1}*g=g, \forall g \in G$$
Similarly, if we first consider $\sigma_{a}$ then $\phi_{a}$, then we get that there exists a $g_{2} \in G$ s.t.
$$g*g_{2}=g, \forall g \in G$$
Now, $g_{1}=g_{1}*g_{2}=g_{2}$, we denote both $g_{1,2}$ by $e$. So $e$ is the identity element of $G$ .

For any $b \in G$， by the surjectivity of $\phi_{b}$, there exists $b_{1}$ s.t. $b_{1}*b=e$. By the surjectivity of $\phi_{b_{1}}$, there exists $b_{2}$ s.t. $b_{2}*b_{1}=e$. We have $b_{2}=b_{2}*(b_{1}*b)=(b_{2}*b_{1})*b=b$, so every element $b \in G$ has an inverse $b_{1}$.